# Calculating the magnetic flux at a certain location

Tags: gauss-law

I am currently preparing for a physics exam and I have troubles solving the question below

a certain location in the southern hemisphere, Earth's magnetic field has a magnitude of 42 microTesla and points upward at 57° to the vertical. calculate the flex through a horizontal surface of area 2.5m².

Comment: What is the definition of the dot product? There you will find your answer

Comment: Welcome to PSE! Please include attempts you have tried to solve the problem or what you don't understand in order to help us help you better. Not doing this might attract downvotes or get your question closed. PSE is not supposed to just solve your problem for you, but help you understand the physics behind, so you'll have more of it.

Comment: Alright thanks, for this I'll take note of that next time, I've been able to work up a solution.